# Why recommended tap target size is in pixels?

Tags: css, pixel

I have seen some guidelines for tap target sizes for mobile devices, and they suggest a 48px by 48px target. However, I am pretty sure that CSS pixels are not absolute measurement and depend on the resolution of the screen. (Increasing the resolution of a screen makes css pixels smaller) If CSS pixels are not absolute, how can a 48 by 48px tap target always work if the size of such a target would change?

Comment: It's because CSS pixels are not absolute that it doesn't matter what the device resolution is - 48 CSS pixels would still be 48 CSS pixels. The size of the tap target won't change.

Comment: 48 CSS pixels will be a different physical length though. Isn't the whole point that the target is a certain physical size. That physical size would no longer be the same if the resolution changes. Right?

Comment: Ah, right, physical size. Presumably they picked that recommended size over something smaller like 40x40 because it's just large enough for the highest-resolution devices that are produced.

Comment: What are your sources?